# Writing down the solutions of system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, determinant

I was solving system of equations using Cramer's rule.

System was

$2x+ay+z=1$

$x+2ay+z= \frac{2}{3}$

$x+ay+2z=1$

Solving determinants I have $D = 4a, Dx = \frac{4}{3}a, Dy = 0, Dz = \frac{4}{3}a$.

Now I have 2 cases, one where $D \neq 0$ and $D = 0$

If $D \neq 0 $, then $a \neq 0$.
In that case there is single solution $(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{3}, 0, \frac{1}{3})$

Now when $D = 0$, then $a = 0$. In that case $Dx=Dy=Dz=0$ so we need to plug in $a = 0$ in the system. We now have:

$2x+z=1$

$x+z= \frac{2}{3}$

$x+2z=1$

Solving we can see that there is infinite solutions to this system and $x=\frac{1}{3}$ $z=\frac{1}{3}$. But now I am not sure what should solutions in this case be. Should it be written down as $(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{3}, y, \frac{1}{3})$ because y can be any number?

Comment: Yes. If $a=0$ case, you have to write as $(x,y,z)=(\frac13,t,\frac13)\ (t\in\Bbb R)$